# Repeat class multiple times without repeating code

Tags: html, css

I would like to repeat div class several times without having to code it, and being able to target each element individually with css. Possible?

Like instead of:

```
<div 
class="design">design</div>
<div 
class="design1">design</div>
<div 
class="design2">design</div>
<div 
class="design3">design</div>
```

I would have:

```
<div 
class="design">design</div> 
X4
```

Is it better to use span class and is this possible to multiply too?

Comment: If each of these `designX` classes is unique you should use an `id` instead. `id="design1"` — IDs are meant to be unique, while the whole point of _**class**_ is that many things can be of the same class. Also, it might make sense to use both: `<div class="design" id="d1">...</div>`

Comment: Like it.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to output your HTML without rewriting it each time, you will need to use one of the following:

- An actual programming language (Such as [PHP](https://www.php.net/))
- A framework/library (such as [React](https://reactjs.org/))
- A preprocessor/templating system (such as [Haml](http://haml.info/) or [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html))

Using PHP is simple enough, if you have PHP installed on your webhost (you almost certainly do).

For instance, instead of this:

## index.html:

```
<div class="design design-0">Design</div>
<div class="design design-1">Design</div>
<div class="design design-2">Design</div>
<div class="design design-3">Design</div>
```

You could have this:

## index.php

```
<?php for( $i = 0; $i < 4; $i++ ){
    echo "<div class='design design-$i'>Design</div>";
} ?>
```

Or check out this Pug example: **https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/OJPvPMX** if you would rather use a preprocessor.

For the CSS though, as @Calvin Nunes said, you can make use of the [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector or even the [Adjacent Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) - though these largely make the need for the `design-x` type classes unnecessary, unless you have other reasons to include them.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly what you want, then I think you can use `nth-of-type(n)`. Although you'll need to repeat code in CSS... (you can avoid repeat HTML code by using Javascript, but since you didn't tagged it and not mentioned nothing about it, I think you want something in HTML and CSS only)

*"The `:nth-of-type()` CSS pseudo-class matches elements of a given type, based on their position among a group of siblings."*

```css
.design:nth-of-type(1){
  color: purple
}

.design:nth-of-type(2){
  color: blue
}

.design:nth-of-type(3){
  color: red
}

.design:nth-of-type(4){
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="design">design</div>
<div class="design">design</div>
<div class="design">design</div>
<div class="design">design</div>
```

And about span, it depends on what you are going to do, `div` is naturally `display:block`, while `span` is `display:inline`

further read about nth-of-type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Comment: Thanks for your post. But it's not possible to do without actually repeating the `div class` 4 times?

Comment: Is that what you need? Does this helps you? If yes, consider to upvote/accept

Answer (score 2):

You could use javascript to accomplish this if you put it in a container.

```
<div id="div_container"></div>

<script>
    let output = "";
    for(i = 0; i<4; i++){
        output += "<div class='design'>design</div>"
    }
    document.getElementById('div_container').innerHTML = output;

</script>
```

You can further style it using .design:nth-of-type(1) .design:nth-of-type(2) etc.

This wouldn't make sense for 4 instances of the div, but more than 10 would be easier and scales to large numbers, simply change 'i' and create the div container.

EDIT:
Define output prior to loop

Comment: @CalvinNunes - Sure, OP didn't mention specifically using JavaScript, but this is a valid answer because it's *implied* that he needs assistance with programatically creating/incrementing divs, RE: `I would like to repeat div class several times without having to code it …`

Comment: True, but OP doesn't mention anything about frameworks either which could be a fair argument. If OP explicitly said that they didn't want any other tools than HTML, I wouldn't recommend this solution. You wouldn't use a drill to cut a plank. I'm offering OP a Saw instead.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly, I'll keep the record from the post upstairs, and no, you can't do it without making it repeat 4 times, each div or the group of divs in this case NEEDS something for you to work with 'em.